# reinterpret quint32 as float

Tags: c++, casting

So unexpectedly (for me) in Qt it's not possible to reinterpret quint32 as float value.

Are there any approaches aside from unions to reinterpret a variable?

```
union
{
 float f;
 quint32 q;
}u;
```

Comment: Qt doesn't have anything to do with it really, it's just plain C++.

Comment: Sounds like a flawed assumption: `reinterpret_cast<float&>(myQuint32Var)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  quint32 i = 666;
  void * vp = &i;
  float f = *(float*)vp;
```

You could also directly cast the address of `i` to a `float *` but that will cause the compiler to complain about breaking strict aliasing rules. Not that inserting a void pointer in between makes it any "better" but at least it doesn't complain.

It works as expected, 666 in binary is `1010011010`, after the conversion `f` is `9.33265e-43`, which is `00000000000000000000001010011010` in binary - the binary representation is the same.

Make sure that when you are making such conversions the destination size is not larger than the source size. In this situation, both quint32 and float are 4 bytes, but if the target is larger than the source, you will be reading "who knows what", which may have negative consequences.

Answer (score -1):

What about QVarinat class from Qt http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html

QVariant(qlonglong val).toFLoat()